Bootstrap5 accordion is not woking in iOS devices
<div className={'accordion'} id={'accordionNav'}>
            <div className={'accordion-item'}>
              <div className={'accordion-header'} id="headingOne">
                <button
                  className={'accordion-button'}
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#collapseOne"
                  aria-expanded="true"
                  aria-controls="collapseOne"
                >
                  We Are StackOverflow
                </button>
              </div>
              <div
                id="collapseOne"
                className={'accordion-collapse collapse show'}
                aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionNav"
              >
                <div className={'accordion-body'}>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link href={'/about-us'} className={'navbar-brand'}>
                        About us
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link href={'/career'} className={'navbar-brand'}>
                        Jobs
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link href={'/contact-us'} className={'navbar-brand'}>
                        Contact Us
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={'accordion-item'}>
              <div className={'accordion-header'} id="headingTwo">
                <button
                  className={'accordion-button'}
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#collapseTwo"
                  aria-expanded="true"
                  aria-controls="collapseTwo"
                >
                  Our Programs
                </button>
              </div>
              <div
                id="collapseTwo"
                className={'accordion-collapse collapse show'}
                aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionNav"
              >
                <div className={'accordion-body'}>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        href={'/example-1'}
                        className={'navbar-brand'}
                      >
                        Example-1 Program
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        href={'/example-2'}
                        className={'navbar-brand'}
                      >
                        Example-2 Program
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={'accordion-item'}>
              <div className={'accordion-header'} id="headingThree">
                <button
                  className={'accordion-button'}
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#collapseThree"
                  aria-expanded="true"
                  aria-controls="collapseThree"
                >
                  Resources
                </button>
              </div>
              <div
                id="collapseThree"
                className={'accordion-collapse collapse show'}
                aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionNav"
              >
                <div className={'accordion-body'}>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link href={'/blog'} className={'navbar-brand'}>
                        Blogs
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link href={'/faq'} className={'navbar-brand'}>
                        FAQ&apos;s
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link href={'/media-mention'} className={'navbar-brand'}>
                        Media Mentions
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={'accordion-item'}>
              <div className={'accordion-header'} id="headingFour">
                <button
                  className={'accordion-button'}
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#collapseFour"
                  aria-expanded="true"
                  aria-controls="collapseFour"
                >
                  Noted Mentions
                </button>
              </div>
              <div
                id="collapseFour"
                className={'accordion-collapse collapse show'}
                aria-labelledby="headingFour"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionNav"
              >
                <div className={'accordion-body'}>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        href={'/mentions'}
                        className={'navbar-brand'}
                      >
                        Mentions
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        href={'/privacy-policy1'}
                        className={'navbar-brand'}
                      >
                        Privacy Policy1
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        href={'/privacy-policy2'}
                        className={'navbar-brand'}
                      >
                        Privacy Policy2
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        href={'/terms-conditions'}
                        className={'navbar-brand'}
                      >
                        Terms & Conditions
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

Above is my html code used. As the collapse is irresponsive in iOS devices I have set aria-expanded="true" for all the items.
I have tried using cursor: pointer on the div with class: "accordion-header", but the behaves the same.
I have also tried with anchor tag () but still the same.
Below are the versions that I'm using for the Bootstrap-5
<Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="your-integrity-value-here" rel="preload" async ></Script>
"dependencies": { "bootstrap": "^5.3.2", },
